# Efficient random sampling from large discrete distribution

Tags: time-complexity, statistics, sampling

I have a random variable $X$ that can take finite values in  $\{X_1, ..., X_n\}$ with probabilities $\{p_1,..., p_n\}$. Is there a computationally efficient way to sample a number from this set? My problem is that $n$ is very large $2^{1000}$. Also the distribution is quite arbitrary - not uniform or something nice.

**Context:** The probabilities are the path probabilities of a 2 state Markov Chain. So in time period $n$, there are $2^n$ paths and I need to sample 100 paths from this set when $n = 1000$

Comment: Thanks @InuyashaYagami, I really did not know how large this number actually was. Now I am kind of hoping to work without having to store the probabilities at all. Basically, using the information that these are path probabilities of a 2 state Markov chain (I have added some context which I should have done earlier).

Comment: Andysack, what prevents you from simulating the Markov chain for $1000$ steps? You can probably take some shortcuts such as sampling a geometric random variable do decide how many steps in the process are spent on the same state.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion! @Steven I guess I was so caught up in looking at the space of paths as the outcome of a random variable that it did not strike me I could just simulate it. Also even a O(n)  algorithm would then need 2^1000 steps since number of elements = 2^1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the probabilities are arbitrary I don't think you can get away with using less than $\Omega(n)$ space. Then there are solutions that use $O(n)$ space, require $O(n)$ preprocessing time, and can return an element selected according to the distribution in constant time.

Have a look at the [Alias method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_method).